# Convert Hand-Written Parser to ANTLR

Tags: java, parsing, antlr

I am currently working on a programming language, and for about 9 months I have been using a hand-written lexer and parser. What I am now trying to do is to convert this to an ANTLR parser. The structure of the [parser system of the compiler](https://github.com/Clashsoft/Dyvil/tree/master/src/compiler/dyvil/tools/compiler/parser) looks roughly like this:

1. Convert the input stream to a doubly-linked token list (done by the lexer).
2. Setup some kind of helper that has a variable `currentParser` and can do things like `reparse()` or `skip(n tokens)`
3. Start parsing with a particular subclass of `Parser` (with the method `parse(ParserManager pm, Token token)`)
4. Depending on the current token, the current parser might `push` a `new Parser` on the *Parser Stack*, or pop itself from the parser stack, meaning that the next parser in the stack will parse the next token.
5. The entire compiler is built up on interfaces like `ITypeList`, that also get passed as single arguments to the parsers.

One example `Parser` subclass is `TypeParser`

```
public TypeParser(ITyped typed) { ... }
```

Or `TypeListParser`:

```
public TypeListParser(ITypeList typeList) { ... }
```

This simple structure applies for *every* single `Parser` implementation. Is there a way to use these interfaces in ANTLR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your descriptions looks like a variant of the Parser combinator pattern.

To convert such a design to ANTLR:

- map the tokens to ANTLR tokens. This is rather easy, since the interface of ANTLR-Tokens and your tokens are similar. They could probably be wrapped or mapped.
- map each parser subclass to an ANTLR parsing rule (or multiple rules). You will need actions and semantic predicates in this parser, since your Parsers are not driven by syntax only
- ANTLR4 does not create an AST, so your AST nodes can be completely recycled, you only have to decide how to create an AST from the grammar:

  1. to create the AST as part of the grammar (actions), this is efficient, but makes your grammar heavily dependent on AST-Classes and Implementation language
  2. to create the AST in a second pass with a parse tree visitor, this decouples parsing and AST construction but an intermediate parse tree is build, which costs some time.